# Ability to batch send multiple NFTs?

Tags: nft

Is there any service that allows you to batch send 10s or 100s of NFTs at once (outside of CLI)?

Answer (score 2):

There's a few, I've personally used [FoxySend](https://famousfoxes.com/foxysend), can highly recommend.